# Getting the ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'From_To': ['LoNDon_paris', 'MAdrid_miLAN',
 'londON_StockhOlm',
'Budapest_PaRis', 'Brussels_londOn'],
'FlightNumber': [10045, np.nan, 10065, np.nan, 10085],
'RecentDelays': [[23, 47], [], [24, 43, 87], [13], [67, 32]],
'Airline': ['KLM(!)', '<Air France> (12)', '(British Airways. )',
'12. Air France', '"Swiss Air"']})
```

The From_To column would be better as two separate columns! Split each string on the underscore delimiter _ to give a new temporary DataFrame with the correct values. Assign the correct column names to this temporary DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.split`

```
df[['From','To']] = df['From_To'].str.split('_',expand=True)
```